# How to add a total row for each grouped row Mat-table angular?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I've been following below stackblitz from @lujjian98 on grouping by rows into expandable panel for mat-table

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping

I've been trying to add a total row in earch grouped rows.

Can anyone advise on how to do this?